# Can I use use_lazy_terminal to make first argument of a terminal that get 3 argument lazy?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I have a custom terminal in `boost::spirit` and I want user to be able to provide first parameter of my terminal as lazy parameter and rest of them as normal literal strings. is this possible using `use_lazy_terminal` for example if in my specialization I use:

```
template<>
struct use_lazy_terminal<qi::domain, my_custom_tag, 1 /*only first parameter*/>
    : mpl::true_ {};
```

@sehe so much thanks for your answer, my concern in this question is not performance and I know that compiler will optimize and ... . let me explain why I create my custom terminal:

As you know compile of `qi` grammars is really slow and finding the source of error is really hard(comparing to simple use of the `qi` itself), so I decided to write a custom terminal that get this: `debug_position( debug_callback, rule_name, msg )`. So I can send custom messages from my rules to a custom debugger, as you see its really simple, I could do this with the help of semantic actions, but using this technique and combining it with a macro that expand to nothing in release mode I can simply write my grammars and debug any of them that I want. But since my messages and rule names are constant, I store them as `const char*` not an `std::string` or something like that, so I think is it possible to first argument supplied from a function but rest of them forced to be literals? I can use `const char (&) [N]` in my specialization of `use_terminal` to force user use string literals.

As you see I can live without this, but I really want to know, can I do this in spirit?

my source code is at: http://pastebin.com/275S6Czu

Comment: I'd really love to see a small example of this. Both because I haven't done a custom terminal with Spirit before, and because it might help me to see where exactly your worries lie.

Comment: Spotted your sample: works out nicely for me: http://liveworkspace.org/code/a43775e74e34c3e1495aa3f907bf5040 (after ironing out the MSVC bugs). What exactly do you want _altered_? I'll update my answer with some more orthodox approaches to debugging grammars.

Comment: @sehe My sample is already working, and I'm already using it to debug my `rules` and `grammars`, but I want to know is there any way that I can get my debugger instance from a global function and force user to provide 2 other arguments as string literal?? as you see in my sample my debugger capture them as raw pointers. I know I can change it `string`, but I'm curious is there any way that only first argument become lazy and 2 others should provided as value??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the exact problem here. Whether or not the code compiles down to literals or references would depend on the calling code.

Much simpler example when using semantic actions:

```
rule1 = int_ [ myactor(_1, phx::val("thisvalue"), phx::cref(instance) ];

// or equivalently

rule1 = int_ [ myactor(_1, "thisvalue", phx::cref(instance) ];
```

Here,

- the first argument is a lazy actor
- the second argument is a *literal*, and it's value (in this case, a `const char(&)[10]`) will get bound. This will pass as a `const char*` on invocation. (`action_dispatch`)
- the third will pass a const reference to `instance`, i.e. it will not copy the value at the time of the `expression template` initialization.

All of this is *compile-time generic*, meaning that you can expect the same code to be generated by your compiler (with optimizations enabled), as when you coded a direct function invocation

```
 myfunction(?, "thisvalue", instance); // assuming instance a const lvalue
```

**Concluding**

I think you can ignore the issue. I'd say *not* treating the arguments as lazy actors would mainly be an *compilation-time optimization* (as in, an optimization to reduce compilation time and template instantiation).

I expect that you should get what you want, by just declaring ***all arguments as 'potentially lazy'<sup>1</sup>***:

- it will copy any actors you pass in as actors
- it wraps any non-phoenix values in val actors - this is a bit different from universal references
- however, the final generated code should 'evaporate' that wrapper layer by inlining it away

**Note** I haven't got the time to check/demonstrate the assertions I make in the above. I'm still throwing this out there, so you can chew on it on your part.

---

<sup>1</sup> looking for a term similar to [*universal references*] here: a *formal parameter type* that 'deduces' (compiles down to) to an actor ***or*** a literal depending on the *actual argument* that gets passed in.

Of course, in this case, literals will just be wrapped in phx::val